# Questions on pgresult and the return of ActiveRecord::Base.connection().execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning ruby and ruby on rails and I've a question :

I would like to know if I can use the select method on a pgresult.

This is my code :

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()

allinfosql = "SELECT applications.appli_name, folders.folder_name, folders.is_obsolete, strategies.strategy_name
FROM applications, folders, strategies, folders_strategies
WHERE strategies.id = folders_strategies.strategy_id 
AND folders_strategies.folder_id = folders.id 
AND folders.application_id = applications.id 
ORDER BY applications.appli_name, folders.folder_name ASC"

@allinfos = connection.execute(allinfosql)
```

I tried to do this

```
test = @allinfos.select {|row| row['appli_name']="SOME_VALUE"}
```

but the result is test is equal to @allinfos

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok I 've done a big mistake. This is work well :

```
test = @allinfos.select {|row| row['appli_name'] == "SOME_VALUE"}
```

So I don't have to convert my pgresult to array. pgresult accept select method.

Thanks for your answer and your help.